# Is it possible to “wake up” the tablet by tapping the screen”?

Tags: android

I have developed one application which is having set of activities and one background service,service will be connected to the server in order to serve request response to and from the server and activities.
Now I have to implement one feature which facilitates wake up the screen by tapping on the phone when my application is running either in foreground or background.
considering sleep mode and keyguard lock , is it possible to achieve the same.

Please help me out to resolve it.

Regards,
Piks

Comment: You are trying to wake up a tablet by tapping on the screen of a phone. And both the tablet and the phone have your application on them and you are transferring data between them via a server. Is this accurate?

Comment: NO,by mistake I mentioned one place tablet and one place phone, please ignore it,  i have one application installed and running on the tablet/phone and this application will be running either on foreground or background So when user touch the screen when device is in sleep mode then it should wake up and screen brightness will again return back to the original from dark.How to achieve it programmatically in android, that's what i want.

Comment: Okay. I thought it might have been a simple typo, but I just wanted to be clear. :) But if the devices screen has gone dark due to it going into sleep mode, then it will stop listening for touch events, so I don't think that what you're wanting is really possible. That and services cannot listen for touch anyway.

Comment: Thanks Jakar :), I was expecting the same answer as I explored so many blogs and found the same so just making sure from you expert because this blog is amazing and really admire for all expert android guys like you.

Comment: @piks have you found the solution of this. I want this too please post as ur answer

Comment: @Qadir sorry to say that , it can't be achieved because when device goes to deep sleep mode, it doesn't listen touch events. So,please check once by acquiring partial wake lock first then try to capture the touch events...partial wake lock make sure that you device's CPU will not be stopped when device is in sleep mode.